# how to send userleft message for telegram in golang

Tags: go, telegram-bot

I'm writing a telegram bot with golang programming language. How can i send a message when a user left or join?
I try this

```
if (message.UserJoined == true){
        bot.SendMessage(message.Chat, "" ,nil)
    }
```

but it does not work and I get this error

```
./main.go:291: invalid operation: message.UserJoined == true (mismatched types telebot.User and bool)
```

Answer (score 1):

UserJoined is a User Struct defined:

// UserJoined might be the Bot itself.

```
UserJoined User `json:"new_chat_participant"`
```

[Found Here](https://github.com/tucnak/telebot/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=UserJoined)

It does not match a bool

Without seeing the rest of the code, I cant tell what you are testing the message for.

I beileve what your needing is something like

```
if message.UserJoined.ID > 0 {
    //Dosomething 
}
```

Comment: yeah this is definitely gonna work based on the library. Something to add if you use this that you will want to make sure the UserJoined field is initialized or this will cause your program to panic trying to access the ID field of uninitialized memory. It looks like this can be nil so watch out for it!

Answer (score 0):

In this case because you are trying to compare two different types it is failing. However, I'm not sure which API you are using or if you are using your own so I'm not sure what message.UserJoined is supposed to represent. However I would think based on your apparent use case that you should be comparing it to nil instead. i.e. use if message.UserJoined != nil {}